# Implementing Chain of Responsibility with Services

Tags: service, chain

I'm thinking about a platform-neutral (i.e. not .NET MEF) technique of implementing chain-of-responsibliity pattern using web services as the handlers. I want to be able to add more CoR handlers by deploying new services and not compiling new CoR code, just change configuration info. It seems the challenge will be managing the metadata about available handlers and ensuring the handlers are conforming to the interface.

My question: any ideas on how I can safely ensure: 
1. The web services are implementing the interface
2. The web services are implementing the base class behavior, like calling the successor

Because, in compiled code, I can have type-safety and therefore know that any handlers have derived from the abstract base class that ensures the interface and behavior I want. That seems to be missing in the world of services.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a valid question, but a rather simple one.

You are still afforded the protection of the typing system, even if you are loading code later, at runtime, that the original code never saw before.

I would think the preferred approach here would be to have something like a properties file with a list of implementers (your chain). Then in the code, you are going to have to have a way to instantiate an instance of each handler at runtime to construct the chain. When you construct the instance, you will have to check its type. In Java, for instance, that would take the form of instanceof (abomination ordinarily, but you get a pass for loading scenarios), or isAssignableFrom. In Objective C, it's conformsToProtocol.

If it doesn't, it can't be used and you can spit an error out to the console.